# Why the truth is always on the opposite direction?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

When I made a mistake, it was always the case that I was totally wrong, not *a little bit* wrong.

Say any idea is a vector which has direction and pointing to a result; what I mean is that the truth is always on the opposite direction of the one I originally believed it was on. I noticed this when I finally understood those confusing parts of math.

I'm learning an idea of programming called neural network, whose ultimate purpose is to create, believe it or not, intelligence as human beings. To make a network useful, it should be accurate about its results/predictions, say about 99% correct for any given testing data set. To make a network accurate as quick as possible, since we hate waiting, one has to find the steepest learning path; you may think of it as learning something *in a hard way*. But this technique will only find a locally suitable solution, which may not be the truth. You may train a network to predict results 99% correct, but it won't be a human.

Is that we are prone to errors/mistakes/fails the reason machine won't be like us?

Comment: It sounds like you may be making a hasty generalization by saying z is always true & you find out other possibilities existed. It sounds as that is when you made your mistake & whatever your conclusions are opposite or going in the other direction. Truths can be constant or contingent. Contingent truths do not hold the truth value. So today is raining may be true but NOT forever true. Programming can work with constant truths well. Currently chess programs are doing what you desire. The computer AI simulates chess player strength. This helps people not have to make perfect games to win.

Comment: How are you defining "the opposite direction?"  I have experienced a feeling which I think lines up with your words, which occurs when I define my concept of "direction" after the fact.  In reality, it's that my mind was only focused on the differences, and had mentally canceled out the commonality.  Are you defining direction after the fact like this, or are you defining direction beforehand, and then observing the results?

Comment: Can you spell out what the question is exactly? One can use fuzzy logic to define what "a little bit wrong" means, but if we are using the binary true/false then not true will necessarily be "all the way" on the other side. And we are using it so broadly because in practical situations one has to decide, to act or not act, not to "act a little bit".

Comment: You can totally post two questions in one, but is the answer you want from the title's question or from the last line's, or both?

Comment: Your first question is about education. Rote learning and some forms of teaching have will have one correct answer. True and false are not the same dichotomy as correct and incorrect. Adaptive learning requires a different approach. And, adaptive thinking processes do not hold the truth to be more than 'the truth for now'. 2nd question; Every machine built is fallible. They are built and designed by very fallible creatures, none of which possess 'the truth'.

Comment: Where did you hear that neural nets are intended to create human intelligence? The truth, in this case, is...in the exact opposite direction from what you believe. An excellent, albeit probably unintentional, example of what you meant by that. But getting back to the main point, the original idea for neural nets was *inspired* by how the human brain works, but they aren't intended to work exactly the same way, nor to create human intelligence. It would not be wise to assume that the mechanisms of either are directly analogous to the other. Neural nets are math, not philosophy or biology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, the truth that you speak of is your subjective truth, a speculative one.

I think Hegel found a good way to contradict Kant's impossibility to understand the truth if I'm not mistaken. To understand truth one must look at the answer in mind as a dual result. Look at the opposite spectrum and find a synthesis, conclusion or union of all possibilities. That would give I think an approximation of a result.

To draw an object you cannot use only light you must also have darkness and the balance of the two will give an accurate representation of the object intended to be drown.